# Is it possible to find Coefficient of Restitution without performing experiment? But only using mathematical equations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, collision, solid-mechanics

I was finding empirical equations to find Coefficient of Restitution (COR) for two solid bodies undergoing collision. Seems like all have used experimentation to find COR. Is there any way to find approximate COR using mathematical formulae?

Comment: A google search for “predicting coefficient of restitution” finds a good number of hits. The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution has a section on predicting from material properties.

Comment: I went through the article, but what if both the materials are not same?

Comment: Then you would need a more general derivation. Maybe that case is so complex that no-one has considered it in any detail.

Comment: Yes, Going by the relation provided in above Wikipedia article (which is in the form of yield strength, Poisson's ratio, elastic modulus and more). I had all the parameters except for yield strength and Poisson's ratio. I was doing it for stainless steel, so i assumed Poisson's ratio = 0.3 and i had tensile strength which is 800 MPa, so i used the relation given in below link to find yield strength from tensile strength.   https://www.twi-global.com/technical-knowledge/faqs/faq-can-the-ultimate-tensile-strength-of-steels-be-estimated-from-the-yield-strength-or-02-proof-strength-values

Comment: But the coefficient of Restitution comes out to be just 0.11 for a velocity of impact of 2 m/s which i think is not right. Also the yield strength from above twi-global link (I used goalseek to find it out) comes out to be 774 MPa, which again i feel is doubtful. Can you comment on the steps i followed?

Comment: You should post your calculations as a separate question on Physics Stack Exchange. But make sure you ask about the general principles too, otherwise your questions may be closed by admins if it is just a "check my work" question.

Comment: Alright, i did not know about this. Apologies for that. But i have got the result, i came here to delete the comment but now since i have got a reply from your end. I will keep it. However, the value of Restitution coefficient i am getting is 0.64.